# Show Header When Not In Iframe

Tags: customization, headers, footer

On our companies website, we have a list of products, then when you click on a product, a popup opens with the product details. Because this was a popup (in a lightbox) I created a `single-productpopup.php` and removed the header and footer.

The problem I have now, is that the Products are showing up in the Sitemap, and therefore search engines (and this is what we want), but when the link is clicked, the `single-productpopup.php` is loaded, and this doesn't have a header or footer, so the visitor has no way to continue navigating around the site.

What I'm hoping is is there a way to detect if the page is being loaded in an iframe, and so do an if statement something like `if page is not in iframe show header and footer`

Or is there a more practical way to do this, maybe with different php files?

Edit: After thought - or add the header and footer with `display: none` by default, and use javascript/jquery to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the header php code, and the setting it with display none as below:

```
#main-header {
  display:none;
}
```

Then using JQuery I added the following:

```
<script>
  if(self==window.top)
  {
  $( "header#main-header" ).css( "display", "inherit" );
  $( "div#mce_height" ).css( "margin-top", "100px" );
  }
</script>
```

This detects if it is in an iframe, and if it's not, it will show the header